# ListView with two different layouts for its children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

For an App I am working on, I have a ListView with a custom adapter. In this ListView I want to give an item either a normal layout or a special layout, so I have the following construction in my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem;

    ...

    if (specialItem) {
        listItem = setUpSpecialItem(convertView);
    } else {
        listItem = setUpNormalItem(convertView);
    }

    return listItem;

}

private View setUpSpecialItem(View convertView) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View listItem;

    if (convertView == null) {
        listItem = new View(mContext);
        listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, null);
    } else {
        listItem = (View) convertView;
    }

    ...

    return listItem;
}

private View setUpNormalItem(View convertView) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View listItem;

    if (convertView == null) {
        listItem = new View(mContext);
        listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.normal_list_item, null);
    } else {
        listItem = (View) convertView;
    }

    ...

    return listItem;
}
```

The problem here is that when populating an item in the list, convertView already has a layout which is usually not the right one. Obviously this creates some large problems in the ListView. Any ideas on how to make this work? I know by the way that I could just make a new View every time, but I'd really like to use convertView for the obvious performance benefits.

Comment: You mean different row inflation for rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desire to reuse the `View` is laudable. However, it is clearly going to fail using you code when the previous `View` is the wrong type. What you need to add is some way of determining if the previous `View` is of the right type:

```
private final static int tagCode = 27835648297; // arbitrary
private final static Integer tagSpecial = 2;
private final static Integer tagNormal  = 1;

private View setUpSpecialItem(View convertView) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View listItem;

    if ((convertView != null) && ((Int)convertView.getTag(tagCode) == tagSpecial) {
        listItem = (View) convertView;
    }
    else {
        listItem = new View(mContext);
        listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, null);
        listItem.setTag(tagCode, (Object) tagSpecial);
    }
    ...

    return listItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know by the way that I could just make a new View every time, but I'd really like to use convertView for the obvious performance benefits.

If the convertView isn't the right type of View, you are going to need to create a new View anyway.

To get whatever benefit you can out of using convertView, you can tag your View's with an appropriate descriptor and check the convertView's tag. For example:

```
private View setUpSpecialItem(View convertView) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View listItem;

    if (convertView == null || !convertView.getTag().equals("special")) {
        // Update the convertView with the correct data
    } else {
        listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, null);
        listItem.setTag("special");
    }

    return listItem;
}
```

Comment: I see, I thought this was the case but I wasn't sure on how to do it. Thanks for your help!